# how to list all docker images info on OpenShift

Tags: image, docker, openshift, podman

I try to list all docker images info on OpenShift ,
like command docker images result, What is the right way to do this?

#oc get images

Comment: docker images --filter "oc"

Comment: Each node could have a different set of images loaded; the nodes will pull images as they're referenced in Kubernetes manifests, and remove them on their own if they become unnecessary.  What leads to needing to do this?  Is there any relevant application code related to this question?

Answer (score 3):

If your question is about how to list all the images that are running inside a cluster, then the command is this one:

```
oc get pods -A -o jsonpath="{..image}" | tr -s '[[:space:]]' '\n' | sort | uniq
```

Answer (score 2):

`oc get imagestreams` but note that TAGS is a comma delimited set